# Difference between BtBn and gyan.dev for FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, manim

I am trying to use ManimGL and the program is not running without FFmpeg or Avconv.
I went to the Official Website, which seems to provide no clue about it.
I went to the repo's README and it leads to the WikiHow page, which again seems to provide no clue for the difference.

What is the difference between these two builds? Which one is better for ManimCE which for ManimGL.

### References

[https://www.wikihow.com/Install-FFmpeg-on-Windows#:~:text=3,they%20become%20available](https://www.wikihow.com/Install-FFmpeg-on-Windows#:%7E:text=3,they%20become%20available).

https://github.com/3b1b/manim#directly-windows

https://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html#build-windows

Comment: The difference is in the specific set of external libraries available.  From what I see in Manim, they only use common functions, so either will do.